# watermark with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

according to this example (http://dimaspriyanto.com/2010/06/08/image-watermarking-with-paperclip/), I try to put a watermark on every picture I upload (for now, I restrain myself to the large one).

And guess what? It doesn't work!

So in my picture model, I have

```
require 'paperclip_processors/watermark'
  has_attached_file :image,
                  :styles => {:medium => "300x300^", :thumb => "150x105^",
                      :large => {
                          :geometry => "460",
                          :watermark_path => ":rails_root/public/images/watermark.png"
                      }
                  },
                  :url => "/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension"
```

and in /lib/paperclip_processors/watermark.rb, I have:

```
module Paperclip
  class Watermark < Processor

    attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :watermark_path, :overlay, :position

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
       super
       geometry          = options[:geometry]
       @file             = file
       @crop             = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
       @target_geometry  = Geometry.parse geometry
       @current_geometry = Geometry.from_file @file
       @convert_options  = options[:convert_options]
       @whiny            = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
       @format           = options[:format]
       @watermark_path   = options[:watermark_path]
       @position         = options[:position].nil? ? "SouthEast" : options[:position]
       @overlay          = options[:overlay].nil? ? true : false
       @current_format   = File.extname(@file.path)
       @basename         = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
     end

      def crop?
        @crop
      end

      def convert_options?
        not @convert_options.blank?
      end

      def make
        dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
        dst.binmode

        if watermark_path
          command = "composite"
          params = "-gravity #{@position} #{watermark_path} #{fromfile} #{transformation_command} #{tofile(dst)}"
        else
          command = "convert"
          params = "#{fromfile} #{transformation_command} #{tofile(dst)}"
        end

        begin
          success = Paperclip.run(command, params)
        rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
          raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
        end

        dst
      end

      def fromfile
        "\"#{ File.expand_path(@file.path) }[0]\""
      end

      def tofile(destination)
        "\"#{ File.expand_path(destination.path) }[0]\""
      end    

      def transformation_command
        scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
        trans = "-resize \"#{scale}\""
        trans << " -crop \"#{crop}\" +repage" if crop
        trans << " #{convert_options}" if convert_options?
        trans
      end

  end

end
```

The watermark is in /public/images/ and it doesn't crash in the process, I mean the pictures are uploaded, in every size but the large one is nude, without the watermark.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the preprocessor that works (I use it)
https://gist.github.com/2499137

Here's sample code for you model:

```
has_attached_file :data,
                  :processors => [:watermark],
                  :url  => "/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/ckeditor_assets/pictures/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
                  :styles => {
                    :thumb => '118x100#',
                    :content => {
                      :geometry => '700>',
                      :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermark.png",
                      :position => 'SouthWest'
                    },
                  }
```

Comment: Ok thanks! So it works but the watermark is resize to match the height of the picture. Can we not resize it?

Comment: What? I didn't scale watermark for me. Is it larger than Image?

Comment: My watermark is 200x50. In the large uploaded picture, it take the height; so on a 400 large pic, it's 400px.

Comment: How would you get a multipage PDF watermarked with a model attribute on every page? I've tried the one on GIST. No Dice. https://gist.github.com/Leventhan/6edd116f7ee43703ebff