# Must specify CLASS - Paperclip Watermark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using [watermark with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517757/watermark-with-paperclip) as a guide to add a watermark to my images.

In other post, I read I could use

```
rake paperclip:refresh Model RAILS_ENV=production
```

I am trying in development environment:

```
rake paperclip:refresh Model
```

And I am having this error

```
rake aborted!
Must specify CLASS
```

I tried with both of my classes Image and the one that is linked with Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this if you are in POSIX

```
export CLASS=Model
export STYLES=style1,style2
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
```

Comment: hmm, I have another problem, but your solution changed problem, so it worked.