# Watermark images with paperclip, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip, watermark

I've been attempting to add watermarks to my images, following the answer listed in [watermark with paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517757/watermark-with-paperclip) :

Watermark.rb:

```
module Paperclip
  class Watermark < Processor
    # Handles watermarking of images that are uploaded.
    attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :watermark_path, :watermark_offset, :overlay, :position

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      geometry = options[:geometry]
      @file = file
      @crop = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
      @target_geometry = Geometry.parse geometry
      @current_geometry = Geometry.from_file @file
      @convert_options = options[:convert_options]
      @whiny = options[:whiny].nil? ? true : options[:whiny]
      @format = options[:format]
      @watermark_path = options[:watermark_path]
      @position = options[:position].nil? ? "SouthEast" : options[:position]
      @watermark_offset = options[:watermark_offset]
      @overlay = options[:overlay].nil? ? true : false
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    # TODO: extend watermark

    # Returns true if the +target_geometry+ is meant to crop.
    def crop?
      @crop
    end

    # Returns true if the image is meant to make use of additional convert options.
    def convert_options?
      not @convert_options.blank?
    end

    # Performs the conversion of the +file+ into a watermark. Returns the Tempfile
    # that contains the new image.
    def make
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
      dst.binmode

      if watermark_path
        command = "composite"
        params = %W[-gravity #{@position}]
        params += %W[-geometry '#{@watermark_offset}'] if @watermark_offset
        params += %W['#{watermark_path}' '#{fromfile}']
        params += transformation_command
        params << "'#{tofile(dst)}'"
      else
        command = "convert"
        params = ["'#{fromfile}'"]
        params += transformation_command
        params << "'#{tofile(dst)}'"
      end

      begin
        Paperclip.run(command, params.join(' '))
      rescue ArgumentError, Cocaine::CommandLineError
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
      end

      dst
    end

    def fromfile
      File.expand_path(@file.path)
    end

    def tofile(destination)
      File.expand_path(destination.path)
    end

    def transformation_command
      scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
      trans = %W[-resize '#{scale}']
      trans += %W[-crop '#{crop}' +repage] if crop
      trans << convert_options if convert_options?
      trans
    end
  end
end
```

and model code:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
                  :processors => [:watermark], 
                  :styles => { 
                    :large => "640x480", 
                    :thumb => "100x100",
                    :medium => "300x300",
                        :content => {
                            :geometry => '150x153',
                            :watermark_path => Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/watermark.jpg'),
                            :position => 'SouthWest'
                        },
                  },
                  dependent: :allow_destroy
```

I've attempted to update this to work with Rails 4 (moving attr_accessor to params in the model), but I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Paperclip::Watermark::PaperclipError
```

Any tips on how to get implement watermarks in a rails 4 app?

**UPDATE:** I was able to get past the uninitialized constant error with Graeme's suggestion below of changing:

```
raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
```

to:

```
raise Paperclip::Error.new("There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}") if @whiny
```

I also had to remove the following from the model in order for the upload to process:

```
:url => "/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension", 
:path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension"
```

**I don't understand what the purpose of :url and :path are in this scenario, when users are uploading images?**

The problem is, even though the images now get uploaded, no watermark is being displayed.  Thoughts?

**Update 2:**
In order to get the watermark displaying correctly, I had to change the model to:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  :processors => [:watermark], 
  :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
  :styles => { 
    :large => "640x480", 
    :thumb => "100x100",
    :medium => { 
            :processors => [:watermark],
            :geometry => '300x300',
            :watermark_path => Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/icon.gif'),
            :position => 'SouthWest'
        },
  },
  dependent: :allow_destroy
```

The key piece was removing :content => .  Only remaining issue is that the watermark is scaling up to fit the entire width of the image.  Any recommendations on how to stop the watermark-scaling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the watermark being stretched is the Imagemagick command which is combining the two images together and then resizing the result.

Effectively the command being run will be (I've abbreviated the actual filenames for clarity):

```
composite -gravity SouthWest icon.gif uploaded_image.gif -resize 300x300 output_image.gif
```

As you see the images are joined and then resized.

The command I believe you need is:

```
convert uploaded_image.gif -resize 300x300 icon.gif -gravity SouthWest -composite output_image.gif
```

i.e. resize the uploaded image and then add on the watermark.

I've tested this using `composite` and `convert` on the command line and it does what I believe you are looking for.

To achieve it in the code, you need to change `if watermark_path` statement in the `make` method:

```
def make

  dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format].compact.join("."))
  dst.binmode

  if watermark_path
    # -- original code --
    # command = "composite"
    # params = %W[-gravity #{@position}]
    # params += %W[-geometry '#{@watermark_offset}'] if @watermark_offset
    # params += %W['#{watermark_path}' '#{fromfile}']
    # params += transformation_command
    # params << "'#{tofile(dst)}'"

    # -- new code --
    command = "convert"
    params  = %W['#{fromfile}']
    params += transformation_command
    params += %W['#{watermark_path}' -gravity #{@position} -composite]
    params << "'#{tofile(dst)}'"
  else
    command = "convert"
    params = ["'#{fromfile}'"]
    params += transformation_command
    params << "'#{tofile(dst)}'"
  end

  begin
    Paperclip.run(command, params.join(' '))
  rescue ArgumentError, Cocaine::CommandLineError
    raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
  end

  dst
end
```

*Disclaimer: I have not actually tested this so please forgive any errors.*

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks so much for the detailed explanations and quick responses!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Please note that in Rails 4.1.0 beta 1 this didn't work for me straight away. Well in fact all was correct but I had to remove :processors => [:watermarks]. For details see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24311129/no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-array-rails-4-1-0-beta1/24317086#24317086 in case you get the following exception: "no implicit conversion of string into array"

Answer (score 2):

`PaperclipError` doesn't exist.

Try changing:

```
raise PaperclipError, "There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}" if @whiny
```

to:

```
raise Paperclip::Error.new("There was an error processing the watermark for #{@basename}") if @whiny
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed the issue, and now I'm able to get through the image upload process.  Problem is that the watermark is not being displayed.  In order to get through the upload (and get images to display properly in my views), I had to remove: 
:url => "/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension",
:path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/:style/:id_:style.:extension",

from the model.  Could that be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are now asking a different question I'll make a new answer.

`:path` is used to define where Paperclip will store the uploaded image.  By default this will be `:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`.

`:url` is used to access the image later.  By default this will be `/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`.

(Actually, to save having to duplicate the url part, `:path` is really defined as `:rails_root/public:url` by default.)

By specifying them in the model you are changing the save location.  I wouldn't recommend putting them in the assets directory as assets are really part of your application and you don't want user uploaded files to be going there.

As to why you are not seeing the watermark with the uploaded image, I guess the Imagemagick composite command is not being called correctly.  Try running it on the command line, or adding the parameter `-debug` to see why it is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; much appreciated.  The issue came down to removing :content from the model.  Working code  updated above.  Thanks!

Only remaining issue is that the watermark is scaling to the full width of the uploaded image (300x300); the watermark itself is (108x22).

Will you please go for the hat trick and help me understand how to keep the watermark from scaling?